# copy a sqlite3 table preserving custom _id

Tags: database-design, sqlite, table

I'm trying to copy a table whose `_id` field is given by integers with some gaps, e.g. 1,2,5,7, presumably due to deleted messages.
(This is a toy-model for a Whatsapp database I'm manipulating.)

I'd like to copy the table preserving the labelling 1,2,5,7, as opposed to 1,2,3,4 that is given by `AUTOINCREMENT` below.

What is the correct way to do it?

```
CREATE TABLE messages (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, key_remote_jid TEXT NOT NULL);
ATTACH 'msgstoreF.db' AS android;
INSERT INTO messages (key_remote_jid)
    SELECT key_remote_jid
    FROM android.messages;
```

I can achieve that by

```
CREATE TABLE messages (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, key_remote_jid TEXT NOT NULL);
ATTACH 'msgstoreF.db' AS android;
INSERT INTO messages (_id, key_remote_jid)
    SELECT _id, key_remote_jid
    FROM android.messages;
```

but then such table is not included in `sqlite_sequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the ID values over:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, key_remote_jid TEXT NOT NULL);
ATTACH 'msgstoreF.db' AS android;
INSERT INTO messages (_id, key_remote_jid)
    SELECT _id, key_remote_jid
    FROM android.messages;
```

Please read the [SQLite Autoincrement documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). New ID values will not conflict with the manually inserted values. (And it is likely that you do not need to specifiy the AUTOINCREMENT keyword.)